# Layering mechanism with Box2D and collision mask bits

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have some problems with creating self configurable collision layers.

My filter categories   are configured like so

```
final short category_00 =     0x0000;
final short category_01 =     0x0001;
final short category_02 =     0x0002;
final short category_03 =     0x0004;
final short category_04 =     0x0008;
final short category_05 =     0x0010;
...
```

next an array with all of these above ( total 16 ) .

```
Array<Short> availableCategories = new Array<Short>();  
availableCategories.add(category_00);
availableCategories.add(category_01);
availableCategories.add(category_02);
availableCategories.add(category_03);
availableCategories.add(category_04);
availableCategories.add(category_05);
```

now, without editor i can simply do

```
short myCustomMask = (short) ( category_02 | category_05 )
```

but i would like to have control about collision matrix , for this i have to create a short which do | ( OR ) on all elements in an custom array ( which will act as a filter mask bit = layer )

```
Array<Short> maskTmp = new Array<Short>(16);
maskTmp.add(i);
maskTmp.add(i+1);
maskTmp.add(i+n);



short myCustomLayer = (short) (maskTmp.get(i) | maskTmp.get(i+1) | maskTmp.get(i+n))
```

I never did anything with bitwise operators and one question is how to do it ? And the second way is this a proper way of doing it ?

Comment: Why is an array involved at all? Also, `category_00` will just be nothing. You won't be able to tell whether you included it or not.

Comment: the idea is to allow in level editor(by UI) to create  categories ( map them to some normal name etc ) and  also create layers. This is only an concept. Basically i want to implement something like in unity, to create layer masks from custom matrix. These user created categories and layers will be saved in project file ( serialized by kryo or sth )